# PDO LIKE return all results when user input %

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following `PDO` with `LIKE` using wildcard `'%'` to match partial results:

```
$value = $_GET["searchValue"];
$dbh = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE ? OR column2 LIKE ?'); 
$query->execute(array("%$value1%","%$value2%"));
```

My issue is that when the user inputs `'%'` or `'%%%%%'`, it returns all values on the `database`, even if don't have anything with saved with `%` symbol con that `row`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the following PDO with LIKE using wildcard '%' to match partial results
>
> when the user inputs '%' it returns all values on the database, even if don't have anything with saved with % symbol con that row.

These two paragraphs above, quite contradicting they are?

You when you're using % yourself, you want it to match any character, but then user is using it, you want it  to match only % literaly. Alas, mysql cannot read minds yet, and cannot tell one % from another.

Frankly, there is no issue at all. Returning all the rows for `LIKE '%%%'` statement is the case % wildcard `is` designed for. If you want to let users to search for the % character literally, you have to escape it with backslash.

Comment: I don't want to escape %. Basically if the user inputs % in the search box by it self it returns all the results stored on the database, but there's not one single row on th Db containing the percent symbol, meaning it should find 0 rows matching %.

Comment: _“I don't want to escape %”_ – but you _have to_, if you want it to mean a literal percent character, and _not_ the wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider only the `$value1` variable.

When the user insert %, PDO makes your query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE '%%%'
```

that's the right behavior.

But, if you want to search (and that's what you want) strings with this pattern
`[anything]%[anithing]` you have to escape the user input, making the query looking like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE '%\%%'
```

To do that, you have to replace the `%` with `\%`.
Basically, the only thing you have to do is to change this line

```
$value = $_GET["searchValue"];
```

in that way

```
$value = str_replace('%', '\%', $_GET["searchValue"]);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: @OzkarR If this answer was useful for you and it has solved your question, please mark it as "Accept answer".